# Core Data with Web Services recommended pattern?

Tags: iphone, web-services, core-data, design-patterns

I am writing an app for iOS that uses data provided by a web service.  I am using core data for local storage and persistence of the data, so that some core set of the data is available to the user if the web is not reachable.

In building this app, I've been reading lots of posts about core data.  While there seems to be lots out there on the mechanics of doing this, I've seen less on the general principles/patterns for this.

I am wondering if there are some good references out there for a recommended interaction model.

For example, the user will be able to create new objects on the app.  Lets say the user creates a new employee object, the user will typically create it, update it and then save it.  I've seen recommendations that updates each of these steps to the server --> when the user creates it, when the user makes changes to the fields.  And if the user cancels at the end, a delete is sent to the server.  Another different recommendation for the same operation is to keep everything locally, and only send the complete update to the server when the user saves.

This example aside, I am curious if there are some general recommendations/patterns on how to handle CRUD operations and ensure they are sync'd between the webserver and coredata.

Thanks much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to read about 'transactions' - which is basically the grouping of multiple actions/changes as a single atomic action/change. This helps avoid partial saves that might result in inconsistent data on server.

Ultimately, this is a very big topic - especially if server data is shared across multiple clients. At the simplest, you would want to decide on basic policies. Does last save win? Is there some notion of remotely held locks on objects in server data store? How is conflict resolved, when two clients are, say, editing the same property of the same object?

With respect to how things are done on the iPhone, I would agree with occulus that "Done" provides a natural point for persisting changes to server (in a separate thread).

Answer (score 1):

I think the best approach in the case you mention is to store data only locally until the point the user commits the adding of the new record. Sending every field edit to the server is somewhat excessive.

A general idiom of iPhone apps is that there isn't such a thing as "Save". The user generally will expect things to be committed at some sensible point, but it isn't presented to the user as saving per se.

So, for example, imagine you have a UI that lets the user edit some sort of record that will be saved to local core data and also be sent to the server. At the point the user exits the UI for creating a new record, they will perhaps hit a button called "Done" (N.B. not usually called "Save"). At the point they hit "Done", you'll want to kick off a core data write and also start a push to the remote server. The server pus h won't necessarily hog the UI or make them wait till it completes -- it's nicer to allow them to continue using the app -- but it is happening. If the update push to server failed, you might want to signal it to the user or do something appropriate.

A good question to ask yourself when planning the granularity of writes to core data and/or a remote server is: what would happen if the app crashed out, or the phone ran out of power, at any particular spots in the app? How much loss of data could possibly occur? Good apps lower the risk of data loss and can re-launch in a very similar state to what they were previously in after being exited for whatever reason.

Comment: +1 I pefer a design in which the Core Data and server elements are not intertwined and capable of working entirely separately. This allows the app to work offline e.g. airplane mode without loss of function. Save data to Core Data and then read it back out to send it to the server. That way makes for a more responsive UI and avoids data loss.

Answer (score 1):

Be prepared to tear your hair out quite a bit. I've been working on this, and the problem is that the Core Data samples are quite simple. The minute you move to a complex model and you try to use the NSFetchedResultsController and its delegate, you bump into all sorts of problems with using multiple contexts.

I use one to populate data from your webservice in a background "block", and a second for the tableview to use - you'll most likely end up using a tableview for a master list and a detail view.

Brush up on using blocks in Cocoa if you want to keep your app responsive whilst receiving or sending data to/from a server.